# Impeachment of judges

Tags: united-states, impeachment, judiciary

What is the procedure when a judge is to be impeached by Congress? Is there a rule on the percentage of votes required when Congress votes?

Comment: I am looking the procedure of both India and USA

Comment: Then please write two separate questions. Asking for both countries at once would make it much less likely that you will get an answer, because the only people who could answer are those who are familiar with **both** systems. When you post two questions, one of them can be answered by an US expert and the other by an India expert. I edited your question to ask about the United States. You might want to post a separate question about India.

Comment: @Philipp Thanks for the suggestion. I didn't think of it that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the same for judges as anyone else:  a majority vote to impeach in the House of Representatives and a two thirds vote (currently 67 if all 100 Senators are there) to convict in the Senate.

Article I, Section 3, paragraph 6 of the [United States constitution](http://constitutionus.com/):

> The Senate shall have the sole Power to try all Impeachments. When sitting for that Purpose, they shall be on Oath or Affirmation. When the President of the United States is tried, the Chief Justice shall preside: And no Person shall be convicted without the Concurrence of two thirds of the Members present.

Paragraph 7 talks about the limitations to punishments that are available.  An impeachment may remove from office and preclude from holding future offices.  However, it is not a criminal punishment, so the person may be referred to the criminal justice system for additional punishment.

The House of Representatives powers are mentioned briefly in paragraph 5 of Section 2 of Article I.  In practice, this has been determined to mean that a simple majority of the voting Representatives may impeach and send to the Senate for trial.

Comment: Just as a brief note:  The procedure is similar for State Level judges in that the Lower House will vote to impeach and the upper house will try the impeachment (In this case, not all states have a House of Representatives.  MD uses Delegates instead of Representatives, though their are little differences between the two roles.  Not sure about the Senate as well).